# Framework to allow users to create report based on json output

Tags: python, django

I want to develop a application which will query a web service and get some data in json. What I want to do is give users a design board which they can use to customize their dashboards which will use the response from the web services . Is there any library of framework I can use, preferably something that integrates with django?

Comment: I am not aware of. And I do think, all the JSON structures and template rules are for most common users too difficult.

Comment: As far as getting your data in and out of JSON format, there is the standard python [json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). However as far as I know, you'll have to do the rest by hand.